# How to use python logging for a single package

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am developing a package and using `logging` module for my debug/info logs during development. Is there a good way to enable logging for just my package without enabling it for everything below root?

Say I have my_package:

```py
# Some package from elsewhere that I need but don't want to see logging from
import other_package  
    
import logging
from logging import NullHandler
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(NullHandler())

def my_func():
    logger.debug("a message")
```

and a main function to use the package:

```py
import my_package
    
# Some package from elsewhere that I need but don't want to see logging from
import another_package

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

my_package.my_func()
```

This setup will let me see `my_func()`'s call to `logger.debug()`, but it will also show any `logger.debug()` calls from other_package and another_package, which I don't want to see.  How can I set things where I only see the logging from my_package?

I could do hacky things like hard-code disable each other package's `logging.propagate` or similar, but that feels like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already defined a unique logger for your package. You just need to configure that. Since the package logger inherits from the root logger, anything you specify with `basicConfig` applies to it as well. You just need to perform logger-specific overrides after you call `basicConfig`.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('my.package').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: damn you're right.  I thought I tried this and it wasn't working, but I must have messed something up the first time.  Maybe I initialized the logging after importing other things before?  Not sure what... anyway this is working for me.  Thanks!